# File-Transfer Cordova como usar php

Tags: php, apache-cordova, file-upload, arquivo

Olá tenho o seguinte código

```
 onDeviceReady: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
                app.uploadPhoto,
                function (message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );
},
uploadPhoto: function(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.168.0.101/upload/index.php"), app.win, app.fail, options);
},

win: function(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
},

fail: function(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
},
```

Ele está funcionando, porem quando eu envio para o meu php eu não sei como salvar, o meu php esta assim:

```
    <?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\images');
    ?>
```

Gostaria de salvar dentro de `C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\images`, como deve ficar o meu php?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer funcionar da seguinte forma, o js ficou assim.

```
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://192.168.0.102/upload/index.php"), app.win, app.fail, options);
```

O index.php recebe e envia-lo para a pasta 'images' dentro de 'upload'.

```
 <?php
    $new_image_name = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$new_image_name);
```

Comment: Se a sua resposta está correta, então marque ela como aceita.